# SQL format of query

Tags: c++, sql, qt5

I'm trying to use this query in a c++ (qt5 embedded):

```
QString query=("declare @TracciatoId int; set @TracciatoId = 76; SELECT Record.TimeStamp AS MarcaturaOraria, DatoNumerico.Valore AS Peso, Record.RecordId FROM Tracciato INNER JOIN Record ON Tracciato.TracciatoId = Record.Tracciato INNER JOIN DatoNumerico ON Record.RecordId = DatoNumerico.Record INNER JOIN Tag ON DatoNumerico.Tag = Tag.TagId WHERE Tracciato.TracciatoId = @TracciatoId");
```

But nothing happen, and I think that the problem is due to the line `declare @TracciatoId int;` and the consequent `set @TracciatoId = 76;` because I'm trying to use string instead of an int. But I don't know how integrate an int into a string flow for my query.
Can you help me?

This is the function in wich I use the query:

```
void DiagramBox::on_Value_Button_clicked()
{
  QString track=ui->lineEdit->text();
  int trackNumber;                       
  bool ok;
  trackNumber = track.toInt(& ok,10);
  QString device=ui->comboBox->currentText();
  this->model=new QSqlQueryModel();

  if(device.compare("'Cella di Carico'")==0){

   QString query=("declare @TracciatoId int; set @TracciatoId = 76; SELECT Record.TimeStamp AS MarcaturaOraria, DatoNumerico.Valore AS Peso, Record.RecordId FROM Tracciato INNER JOIN Record ON Tracciato.TracciatoId = Record.Tracciato INNER JOIN DatoNumerico ON Record.RecordId = DatoNumerico.Record INNER JOIN Tag ON DatoNumerico.Tag = Tag.TagId WHERE Tracciato.TracciatoId = @TracciatoId");


   QByteArray ba = query.toLocal8Bit();
   const char *m_device= ba.data();
   model->setQuery(m_device);

   ui->tableView_2->setModel(model);
  }
```

In a previous query this code schema work fine:

```
void DiagramBox::on_Tracks_Button_clicked()
{
   ui->Value_Button->setEnabled(true);
   this->model=new QSqlQueryModel();

   QString device=ui->comboBox->currentText();

   if(device.compare("'Cella di Carico'")==0){
      QString query=("SELECT [TracciatoId],[Dispositivo],[DataCreazione],[TankId]FROM [IFaCOM].[dbo].[Tracciato] INNER JOIN [IFaCOM].[dbo].[Dispositivo] ON Tracciato.Dispositivo = Dispositivo.DispositivoId WHERE Dispositivo.Descrizione = "+device);
      QByteArray ba = query.toLocal8Bit();
      const char *m_device= ba.data();
      model->setQuery(m_device);
      ui->tableView->setModel(model);
   }
}
```

The difference between the two queries seems just in the int parameter of the second query.

Comment: looks ok to me.  How are you using the `query` variable -- your problem is probably there.

Comment: @Hogan I tried to use this query in Sql Server Managment Studio and it works fine....

Comment: @Hogan If you want I can post how I use the query in my code

Comment: nothing is supposed to happen. This is just a string.

Comment: is there a fix value for `@TracciatoId` param????

Comment: @nurettin of course, but I use the query inside the   QString query is used after to display in a tableView oject the records specified in the query...

Comment: @joker The value of Tracciato Id is not fix, but is fix the type: int

Comment: @CecchinoSMI The problem might be that select is not the first statement in your query. I suggest you try using `QSqlQuery::prepare` and `QSqlQuery::bindValue` to set parameters.

Comment: try to enclosed 76 with '76' or ('76')

Comment: @joker No sorry...nothing...doesn't work

Comment: @nurettin I can try, but as I said previuosly, this query work fine in the SqlServer Management Studio...

Comment: @CecchinoSMI - don't use joker's code it is wrong and even fixed (convert `a` to string) would be open to injection attacks.

Comment: @joker No nothing....

Comment: @Hogan Ok...I post something

Comment: hogan already say that's wrong. . .
post some more code then hogan may help you. . .

Comment: @Hogan Consider that I used the same code with a previous query to show datas in an other tableView  and it works fine.

Comment: @CecchinoSMI yes you have established that the problem is not on MSSQL side. That's why I guessed that it is on Qt side.

Comment: @nurettin But I used other querys in qt side...and they work fine...the format of the other query is the same of the code that I posted :(

Comment: @CecchinoSMI oh ok sorry I don't know what else could be wrong, then. I'd just try doing it properly with `bindValue` and looking at the logs for any error (in mssql case, you could take a look at the sql profiler, too)

Comment: I don't know qt well but it seems the auto data binding does not execute inn batch mode... Check the docs for how to enable batch

Comment: Also in the prior query that worked what was different?

Comment: @Hogan I post the previous code...with the previous query.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by deleting the declaration and definition of the parameter `Tracciato Id`at the biginning of the code...seems that Qt can't use this kind of declaration.
Anyway thanks to all.

Comment: Yes it was clear this was the problem when comparing the two queries.  I was about to write such a comment when I saw your answer.

Comment: Also, to note, you seem to think the 2nd query is "taking a parameter".  This is not how parameters work in SQL.  I'd check out the Qt documentation for the correct way to pass parameters.